# Using plyer with qpython

Tags: qpython

Sorry if this is too obvious but I am trying the following under qpython on Android:

```
from plyer import notification
notification.notify("something","else")
```

and I get errors which end with:

```
NotImplementedError: No usable implementation found!
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

notify must be passed several arguments, here is a example of how to use it:

```
from plyer import notification

notification.notify(title="Kivy Notification",message="Plyer Up and Running!",app_name="Waentjies",app_icon="icon.png",timeout=10)
```

hope this helped